# Click na imagem não funciona com box-sizing

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá, estou com um problema..
Em uma imagem do meu site, que possui ID #imagem, quando clicada ela executa um código em jquery, como o abaixo:

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#imagem").click(function(){
        $("#div1, #div2").css("display", "none");
    });
});
</script>
```

Problema é que, a imagem, quando clicada não executa a ação ali definida, mas se eu ir na página, e mudar o atributo `border-sizing` para `content-box` ou tira-lo (da na mesma, porquê sem o padrão é ser content-box) ai minha imagem executa ação quando clicada.
O que pode ser que, só funcione quando tiro o atributo `box-sizing: border-box`, ou troco para `content-box` por exemplo?

CSS da imagem:

```html
     <span id="imagem"><img src="img.png" border="0" class="img-responsive"/></span>
```

Basicamente é a classe img-responsive do bootstrap!
o span tem a id #imagem, pois o jquery verifica se houve algum clique naquele span, como no span tem só aquela imagem, logo a imagem vai executar o jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obrigado..
Mas o erro foi meu, acabei revendo aqui, e vou deixar esclarecido o que foi..
Bom, estava usando o bootstrap para deixar a página responsiva, então as divs estão todas no padrão do bootstrap(classes eram: col-sm-12, col-sm-8..), respeitando o que eles pregam!
Porém, deixei uma DIV(essa div que continha o span, que por desta vez este span continha essa imagem que requisitava o Jquery no click), mas essa DIV não estava aos padrões do Bootstrap(a classe era outra, uma que eu criei), ai, embaixo dessa div tinha outra DIV no padrão do bootstrap(col-sm-12) que praticamente encobriu essa minha DIV que estava fora dos padrões, que por sua vez não possibilitou que eu clica-se no botão, pois a DIV encobriu.

Quando eu falei de, box-sizing, que eu mudei de border-box para content-box funcionou, é porque no content-box ele acaba **separando todas as divs, e isso deixou a DIV antes encobrida, descobrida!**

Espero que tenham entendido, para os futuros que passaram por aqui entenderem!

Comment: Ok. Com base nessa sua resposta, achei melhor marcar a questão como um problema que não pode ser reproduzido (veja a explicação do motivo de fechamento acima).

Answer (score 0):

Tente mudar o seu método para `.hide()`, invés de `.css("display", "none")`

Exemplo:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#imagem").click(function(){
        $("#div1, #div2").hide();
    });
});
```

[Método .hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)